# Sharepoint:ClientPeoplePicker can't search user by Japanese kanji name when type only 1 character

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I'm having a problem with search function of user control in Sharepoint (Sharepoint:ClientPeoplePicker). User needs to type kanji name in this field to search for users.

If user inputs more than 2 Japanese characters, the search function will work well. However, if user only types 1 character (’大’, for example), this control doesn't return any result, but the expected result must be 17 users. 
Any solution?

P/s Ignore the case of copy-paste, I care only about typing

Comment: I can be wrong but this is by design in a default people picker. Microsoft wrote it that way i guess

Comment: Would be better if there's an document talks about it. I need to prove to customer

Comment: I did the test on my local environment and i can confirm that it only searches when you type more than 2 characters. I googled a bit but did not found this specification in official ms documents. Good luck though ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Not sure is there anyway to create a custom control that resolve this issue ?

Comment: check this: http://www.threewill.com/tired-of-sharepoint-people-picker-have-it-your-way/ and don't forget to adjust the minimumInputLength parameter as its also on 3 by default :D